# Python Selenium - Website Behaves Differently

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scrape some tables from a Web site. The page displayed in Chrome browser has all the tables I need. With Selenium I get a page requesting me to login instead of the page displayed in the browser. This is new behavior starting this week because the code worked until last weekend. What do I need to do to retrieve the tables?

My code is as follows:

```
import time
import selenium.webdriver
import fake_useragent
import bs4


def get_driver() -> selenium.webdriver.Chrome:
    driver_path = "D:/selenium/chromedriver.exe"
    options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")  # this is required
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--log-level=2')
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging', 'enable-automation'])
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")

    user_agent = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')

    return selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)


def get_soup(url: str, errormsg: str, sleep: int = None):
    driver = get_driver()
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        if sleep is not None:
            time.sleep(sleep)
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, features="lxml")
    except:
        soup = None
        print(errormsg)
    finally:
        driver.quit()
    return soup


if __name__ == '__main__':
    url: str = "https://www.barrons.com/market-data/market-lab/beta"
    soup = get_soup(url=url, errormsg=f"barrons: get failed for {url}")
    if soup is not None:
        tables = soup.find_all("table")
```

Comment: Umm... you need to log in first.

Comment: You don't need to login when you view the page in the browser. Try https://www.barrons.com/market-data/market-lab/beta in Chrome browser.

Comment: I tried without headless mode, and it did not ask for login.

Comment: @scorpio it asked me to login

Comment: When I comment out the line "options.add_argument('--headless')", I am still getting the login page. Did you run my script?

Comment: I ran your script (commenting out the `driver_path` bits b/c my Chromedriver is on my path), and it ran perfectly fine - ended after 8.6 seconds with no errors. When I commented out the headless bit, a window popped up briefly and looked like it might be loading the login page, but it closed again. Still no errors.

Comment: I commented out driver_path and added the folder containing Chromedriver to my path. But it made no difference. I am still getting the login page. My driver version matches the browser version. Not sure why I am seeing a different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My script is working today even though I made no changes. I think there may have been some glitch with the Web site yesterday.